# AngularJS Grunt load JS file with dynamic query string parameter

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am developing application with yeoman + grunt + angularJs.

To load the JS file only when require I have added JS file path inside calendar.html.

To achieve this I have modified grunt.js and html file.

**Grunt.JS file**

```
useminPrepare: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html', '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/*.html'],
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            flow: {
                html: {
                    steps: {
                        js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                        css: ['cssmin']
                    },
                    post: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Modified calendar.html file**

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/fullcalendar.js -->
  <script src="scripts/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This solution is working properly. But now whenever I load my Calendar page a fresh request goes to fullcalenar.js with dynamic query string parameter like this

```
http://localhost/scripts/fullcalendar.a13f9b72f8.js?_=1422010995753
```

This number (1422010995753) increments every time I make a request which stop browsers from caching the file.

I believe it is because of assetCacheBuster but here is my configuration of Grunt. And I have set that to false along with debugInfo.

```
   compass: {
        options: {
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: './bower_components',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false,
            raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: false
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is, I want to cache the fullcalendar.js file and don't want to fetch the fresh JS file every time.

If I move above calendar.html code inside index.html file application works properly and cache the file without combining with rest of the js. But if I add that code inside index.html, the fullcalendar.js file will get loaded with first page itself.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer: [grunt-cachebuster-querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cachebuster-querystring)